# SQL Server constraint subqueries not allowed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 3 tables:

1. employees
2. departments
3. employees_departments (join table between employees and departments with additional info)

The department also has a column `manager_id` which is a foreign key to the `employees` table (a department has a manager from the employees table).

I have a requirement in which I must place a constraint in which no employee under a manager can have a higher salary than the manager.

My attempt at solving this:

```
ALTER TABLE employees 
    ADD CONSTRAINT check_salary 
        CHECK (salary > (SELECT salary
                         FROM employees e2
                         INNER JOIN employees_departments ed2 ON e2.id_employee = ed2.id_employee
                         INNER JOIN departments d2 ON d2.id_department = ed2.id_department
                         WHERE e2.id_employee != manager_id (but how do I get the manager id)
                           AND d2.id_departament = manager_department_id (again don't know how to do get it)
)
```

I get an error that subqueries are not allowed. Is this even possible to do in a constraint? How can it be modeled in a normal query?

I must also add that I have close to none experience with SQL Server and very little with SQL in general.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't use a subquery directly in a check constraint. You could use a scalar UDF but these in check constraints have lots of issues.

Comment: Note, what you really want is a foreign key constraint. That said, to get a "query" into a check you can write a function that contains the query and outputs a scalar value, then use that function in the check constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could do this, what would you expect to happen when the data changes such that for some rows the constraint fails (like a manager gets a salary reduction)? Sounds like this might be a bad problem/business rule description.

If it's purely an insert/update time check then use code or (yuk) a trigger.

Another alternative might be to use an updatable view which only selects employees that earn below their manager (i.e. everyone). By updating and inserting there you might be able to make it work in every case because if the insert/update into the view would not satisfy the view's criteria it will reject it.

Read up on the view and specifically the `WITH CHECK OPTION`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql